# Use Link in React Component Rendered on Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using pay pals react engine. I have my layout component which calls my Nav component. Since Nav is global I wanted to put it within Layout, both seem to be rendered server side. The problem comes when I want to use react routers Link function in Nav.

Layout:

```
var React = require('react');

var Nav = require('../../server/components/Nav.jsx');

module.exports = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function(){
        try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}
    },

    render: function render() {
        return (
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charSet='utf-8' />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <title>
                    {this.props.title}
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>

            { /*trying to pass router as a prop as a useless attempt to make this work*/ }
            <Nav router={this.props.router} />
            <div className="wrap">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
            </body>
            <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
            </html>
        );
    }
});
```

Here is my Nav component. You can see within the UL tag I am using anchor elements. I would like the use the  tag so react router will do its thing rather than having to send a new request to the server. I've tried a few different things to make it would however I've been unsuccessful. Is it even possible to use react router in a component rendered from the server?

```
var React = require('react');
var Logo = require('./logo.jsx');

var Nav = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var mobileMenuShow = function(e){
            var el = e.currentTarget;
            var list = document.querySelector('.main-nav-list');
            if(el.innerHTML === '+'){
                el.innerHTML = '-';
                list.setAttribute('class', 'main-nav-list open');
            } else{
                el.innerHTML = '+';
                list.setAttribute('class', 'main-nav-list');
            }
        };
        return (
            <nav className="background-first main-nav">
                <section className="nav-wrap">
                    <section className="main-nav-left">
                        <div className="main-nav-logo"><Logo /></div>
                        <div className="plus-icon" onClick={mobileMenuShow}>+</div>
                    </section>
                    <section className="main-nav-right">
                        <ul ref="navList" className="main-nav-list">
                            <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Quick Start</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </nav>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, yes. As long as you have a client router kick off after the page is rendered from the server. Basically, if the only router in on the server, then it will always handle the requests. But, if you have one loaded in the client too, then it will pick up the client transitions and only use the server when you do a page reload (F5) or enter a new URL. [Check out the React Router Mega Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo) to see how the `client.js` file is also creating a router after the app is loaded from the server.

To accomplish the `Link` / `<li>` issue, you just need to create a component to return the link inside of a tab.

Here's an example of how to accomplish this ([taken from issue 666](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/666)).

```js
var NavTab = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: router: React.PropTypes.func
    },
    render: function () {
        var isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, this.props.params, this.props.query);
        var className = isActive ? 'active' : '';
        var link = (
            <Link {...this.props} />
        );
        return <li className={className}>{link}</li>;
    }

});
```